# Не срабатывает аутентификация

Tags: php, сессия, traits

Привет всем!
Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку.

При аутентификации как видно из кода должны присваиваться значения глобальной переменной `$_SESSION` и происходить редирект на другую страницу. Но почему-то ничего не происходит.

**init.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
use Parsclick\Sessions\PersistentSessionHandler;
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$handler = new PersistentSessionHandler($db);
session_set_save_handler($handler);
session_start();
$_SESSION['active'] = time();
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
require_once './includes/init.php';
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $pwd = trim($_POST['pwd']);
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT pwd FROM `users` WHERE username = :username');
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stored = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    if (password_verify($pwd, $stored)) {
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
        if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
            // create persistent login
            $autologin = new AutoLogin($db);
            $autologin->persistentLogin();
        }
        header('Location: restricted1.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        $error = 'Login failed. Check username and password.';
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Auto Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Persistent Login</h1>
<?php
if (isset($error)) {
    echo "<p>$error</p>";
}
?>
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
        <label for="remember">Remember me </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Log In">
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

А просто страница **login.php** выдает 3 таких ошибки по отношению к трем свойствам

> Strict standards: Parsclick\Sessions\MysqlSessionHandler and
>   Parsclick\Sessions\PersistentProperties define the same property
>   ($table_sess) in the composition of
>   Parsclick\Sessions\PersistentSessionHandler. This might be
>   incompatible, to improve maintainability consider using accessor
>   methods in traits instead. Class was composed in
>   /path/to/project/test.loc/Parsclick/Sessions/PersistentSessionHandler.php
>   on line 65

и 2 ошибки по отношению к сессиям

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   /path/to/project/test.loc/Parsclick/Sessions/PersistentSessionHandler.php:65)
>   in /path/to/project/test.loc/test/includes/init.php on line 11
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /path/to/project/test.loc/Parsclick/Sessions/PersistentSessionHandler.php:65)
>   in /path/to/project/test.loc/test/includes/init.php on line 11

Comment: session_start(); должна быть первой строкой.
Замечание:
Для использования сессий на основе cookie, функция session_start() должна быть вызвана перед выводом чего бы то ни было в браузер.

Answer (score 0):

По порядку.

В сообщениях, которые касаются `login.php` - вам там вполне понятно объясняют, что у вас в классах, которые вы используете, переопределяется свойство `$table_sess` - это позволительно, но в целом неверно. Найдите, где и в каких классах оно у вас объявлено, и оставьте только в одном из них, либо назовите его иначе в одном из классов, если хранимое там значение на самом деле обозначает не одно и то же.

В сообщениях, которые касаются сессий, вам точно также пишут, что все, касаемое заголовков `http`-ответа, должно быть передано до вывода тела ответа. Если по-русски, то то, что ваш браузер получает в `headers` (не путать с тегами `head`/`header` в `html`), веб-сервер должен отправить до того, как отправить собственно тело ответа, то есть в вашем случае это саму html-страницу, а точнее - сделать первый вывод чего бы то ни было, например вывести что-либо через `echo` или просто закрыть тег `<?php ?>` и напечатать после него какой-либо текст.

Если взять это за правило и выводить все, что должно быть в хедерах (а это и про сессии, и про кеширование, которые у вас упомянуты в ошибках), то все будет работать верно.

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали переименовал свойства трейта. Теперь все ошибки пропали. Но все равно сессионные переменные не присваиваются, и не происходит редиректа. Присваиваются, но при обновлении страницы аннулируются. Вообще не понимаю что происходит.

Comment: @phpХ А про какие именно переменные идет речь?

Comment: $_SESSION['username'] и $_SESSION['authenticated']

Comment: @phpХ а выложите обновленный код где-нибудь.

Comment: Могу вот архивчик. [архив](https://yadi.sk/d/jFYihH3d3KHzHe)